# Manual Backup - How to save to Firefox or Chrome (instead of IE which brings up popup I can't get rid of)

Tags: plugins, customization, options, server

It appears my question isn't in the list provided...

My question pertains to doing the Export backup method and the .xml file saving to Internet Explorer which causes an automatic IE popup. (I use Firefox & Chrome and abandoned IE long ago...).

This popup is challenging because it not only forces me to choose "home page and search settings", it is such that I can't get rid of the popup or leave that screen unless I select one of the options provided (i.e.: it prompts me to click either "Microsoft Settings" or "Current Settings").

My problem is that I'm leery of clicking on one of the choices (and from what I have read by others who have the same problem I'm not alone and also that nothing even happens anyway when they DO make a selection) so I end up shutting down my computer just to get rid of it.

My main question is:
In order for me to do the Tools Export backup method before a WPClone backup, is there a way to have the .xml file save to Firefox or Chrome so that IE isn't involved and won't cause the popup...?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll say what anybody reading this would say: what?!

I mean, short answer: don't open the .xml file but just save it.

Your OS seems to be configured to open .xml with IE.

Create a random .xml file on your desktop, right click, define the "open by default with..." don't select IE but notepad.exe or any text editor you have at home. Then download you file, SAVE IT (and don't open it).

I mean that's not really a Wordpress related question and more a basic Windows OS related question.

Tell me if i understood your problem well (which i'm note sure i did)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! (Oops sorry, I see what you mean now about this being more a Windows OS related question...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! (Oops sorry, I see what you mean now about this being more a Windows OS related question...) Thank you for giving me my new search terms! (how to re-configure Windows so .xmls don't open with IE)  I tried your suggestion to create and save the .xml file to my desktop, etc. but the instructions I read to do that didn't match anything I was seeing in Programs to follow through to be able to complete that (sigh...) Will keep at it, thx again!

Comment: You totally helped me get back on track! It worked :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help you @Paje as i'm mainly a Linux user i could'nt exactly guide you with the precise terms of the menus etc... Hope you managed anyway ! If this solved your problem don't hesitate to rate the answer and mark the thing resolved :)